# How to add color to Link in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working with react router dom and trying to give style to active link.

The problem is when I give the active style to the url '/' and when I click another Link, this active style does not leave. Why can it happen?

I mean I click the Link to the url '/' , everything works ok, when I click another Link, the Link with url '/' has active style, but I have already opened another page.

My code is below:

```
const SideBar = () => {
    
    const getStyle = (isActive:boolean) => {
        return isActive ? 'activePage' : 'inactive'
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="sidebar-overlay">
            <ul className="sidebar-content">
                <li>
                    <NavLink
                        className={({isActive}) => getStyle(isActive)}
                        to={'/'}>
                        <Home/>
                        Главная
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink
                        className={({isActive}) => getStyle(isActive)}
                        to={'/sections'}>
                        <Sections />
                        Отделы
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink
                        className={({isActive}) => getStyle(isActive)}
                        to={'/accounts'}>
                        <Accounts />
                        Учетные записи
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
};
```

```
function Application () {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="content">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Header/>
                    <SideBar/>
                    <Routes>
                            <Route path='/' element={<Main/>}/>
                            <Route path='/sections' element={<Sections/>}/>
                            <Route path='/accounts' element={<Accounts/>}/>
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
.activePage {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.inactive {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: The `NavLink` already has active "state", there is no need to add your own. The `"/"` link matches any route so just use the `end` prop to exactly match a path that ends with `"/"` to only highlight the root home route when actually on that path.

Comment: What does end prop mean? How then to write Link properly?

Comment: Trivially as `<NavLink className={....} to="/" end>....</NavLink>`.

Comment: Yes, this solution is incredibly good! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define a state to represent the currently active page and change the class accordingly:

```
const SideBar = () => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className='sidebar-overlay'>
      <ul className='sidebar-content'>
        <li>
          <NavLink className={active === '' ? 'activePage' : 'inactive'} onClick={() => setActive('')} to={'/'}>
            <Home />
            Главная
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            className={active === 'sections' ? 'activePage' : 'inactive'}
            onClick={() => setActive('sections')}
            to={'/sections'}
          >
            <Sections />
            Отделы
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            className={active === 'accounts' ? 'activePage' : 'inactive'}
            onClick={() => setActive('accounts')}
            to={'/accounts'}
          >
            <Accounts />
            Учетные записи
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: While this may technically work, the `NavLink` already has active "state", why duplicate this logic when you can just use the correct `end` prop to exclude matching `"/"` when on another path?